# Sharing a database between a react native app and an embedded SPA?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native, single-page-application, embedded-database

I've a simple react native application (CRUD) that persists to X database (realm, sqlite, pouchdb) and this app have an embedded SPA running inside using [react-native-static-server](https://github.com/futurepress/react-native-static-server), this SPA is like a web interface for view the data inside the app:

[image]

The issue is that I need to access to the database of the react native app from js, here my attempts:

1. [realm-js](https://github.com/realm/realm-js), realm database doesn't works in browser.
2. [pouchdb-react-native](https://github.com/stockulus/pouchdb-react-native/), this bridge doesn't allows specify path for db file, [issue #72](https://github.com/stockulus/pouchdb-react-native/issues/72)
3. sqlite using [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage), same that above.

How would you approach this issue?

Thanks.

***ps: offline is a requirement, so api is not allowed.***